# 400_Bad_Request when consuming REST API - randomly and lasts for a couple of hours?

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest

I have coded a REST API myself that consumes another REST API.

It often works, but it also often results in 400_Bad_Request.

The flow is this: it works, works, works for so long and then it doesn't work, doesn't work and doesn't work for so long. I then just take a break and after an hour or two, it works again. **It doesn't matter what browser I use - chrome or firefox (but I did try clearing the cache)**. If I enter the URL directly in my browser (that I am trying to consume in my web-service), then I get proper response, so it's not like they block my ip-address for a little while.

```
    public function apiFunction()
    {

        parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
        $host = "THE API ADDRESS"; //omitted due to privacy
        $tran = new apiCallClass( "username", "pwd" ); //omitted due to privacy  
        $tran->setSomeData( $var1, $var2, $var3 ); 
        $tran->setSomeRequest( $var4, $var5 ); 
        $tran->setSomeField("somevar", $var6); 
        $tran->setHost( $host ); 
        $tran->execute(); 
        parse_str($tran->ResponseRaw,$theArr);
        //... other code goes here, 
        //but I can already see ResponseRaw has 400_Bad_Request
    }
```

**This is the function that could be the source of the problem: if I copy the value of $url and paste it in browser, it works, so it must be something that this function is doing that's wrong:**

```
function processRequest( $url ) 
{ 
     $temp = $url;
     $ch = curl_init($url); 
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE); 
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE); 
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE); 
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
     if ( !$this->isBlank($this->ProxyHost) ) 
     { 
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP); 
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$this->ProxyHost); 
     } curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120); 
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
     $this->parseResponse( curl_exec($ch) ); 
}
```

Comment: What part of apiFunction is perhaps time-based? Or what part of it could changed significantly between one hour and the next?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa Nothing actually. Plus I pass same parameters in direct browser request and that comes out fine.

Comment: Perhaps you have spyware or something intercepting your requests?

Comment: @TashPemhiwa Other people tried it too. I even got fed up of trying it on localhost and made someone host my api. Still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to contact the API provider if you make the exact same request and the response doesn't return any message body other than the 400 status code.

I suspect you're reaching some kind of rate limit if you're performing lots of requests from the same IP address (they should return a 429 Too Many Requests but I've seen many APIs returning 400 for rate limits).

Comment: but why does browser work fine during the same period my code is not working? Browser has the same ip-address obviously.

Comment: Indeed. In that case, the only differences are cookies and headers (like the user agent). Have you tried to manually curl or wget that url from the command line?. Try to also to dump the content of the response before parsing it to see if there is any response body. curl_getinfo($ch) can also give you additional information about it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: I download curl.exe with ssl enabled for windows. It works. Why is my code not working?! curl_getinfo didn't lead to anything useful.

Comment: I added curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); and it's better now, but who am I to say it won't break again? There's no sure way to test it?